# Sum up values with dynamic grouping conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to **sum up values with dynamic grouping conditions in only one query**, if possible. That also means **no** `UNION ALL`.
(The query below is quite easy and `UNION ALL` wouldn't be expensive at all, but if the source data has to be gathered from a bunch of tables it decreases performace to do all joins twice.)

**Example data:**

```
create table data (id int, location nvarchar(1), qty int, grouping tinyint)

insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (1, 'A', 10, 0)
insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (1, 'A', 20, 0)
insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (1, 'B', 15, 0)
insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (2, 'A',  5, 1)
insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (2, 'B', 10, 1)
insert into data (id, location, qty, grouping) values (3, 'B', 20, 1)
```

Qty should be summed up per location, if grouping is 0, else per id.

**Estimated result:**

```
1, A, 30
1, B, 15
2, null, 15
3, null, 20
```

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb6656/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, using `CASE WHEN ...`

```
SELECT  id ,
        (CASE WHEN grouping = 0 THEN location ELSE NULL END) AS location,
        SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM    data 
GROUP BY id ,(CASE WHEN grouping = 0 THEN location ELSE NULL END)
ORDER BY id
```

Result:

```
id  location    qty
1   A           30
1   B           15
2   NULL        15
3   NULL        20
```